# second frame not using values from default-frame-alist

Tags: init-file, frames

I'm just starting to customize emacs on RHEL8, the entirety of the `.emacs` file is this:

```lisp
(setq default-frame-alist '((width . 80) (height . 40) (menu-bar-lines . 1)))
```

When starting Emacs this sets the first frame size appropriately. However, when I create a new frame `(C-x 5 2)` the new frame does not use these values (it is tiny instead). How do I get subsequent frames to respect the size?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that, when I start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, in any official Emacs release (up through 27.2, which is the most recent release).

1. Try `-Q` instead of `-q`, to see if the problem is with your `site-lisp.el`.
2. State what version of Emacs you're using (`emacs-version`) and on what platform.
3. Check that `C-x 5 2` is bound to `make-frame-command`.  If it's not, and you're using `emacs -Q`, then you're likely using some prelease version of Emacs, where the behavior of that key has changed (a backward-incompatible change).
4. Consider filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.